# Include file owner to powershell pipe

Tags: csv, powershell

I've got a script which works fine which lists all files modified since last 7 days and want to modify it to add file owner to the export csv file.

```
 $dir_to_look="F:\"    
 $month_backdate=$(Get-Date).AddDays(-7)    
Get-Childitem $dir_to_look -Recurse | ? { !($_.psiscontainer) -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $month_backdate } | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName}.owner | Select-object LastWriteTime, Directory, FullName  |  export-csv -path \\sharename\report.csv -encoding "unicode"
```

But not sure how to correctly add get-acl to the pipe as currently it prints nothing to my report file

Answer (score 1):

Your Foreach-Object command should be:

```
... | Foreach-Object {Add-Member -Input $_ -Type NoteProperty -Name Owner -Value (Get-Acl $_.Fullname).Owner -PassThru} | Select-object LastWriteTime, Directory, FullName, Owner | ...
```

`Add-Member` is handy for adding properties (and methods) to objects.

Comment: Also need to edit the following `Select-Object` to include the new property `owner`

Comment: Yup, added that as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Unfortunately it does not write Owner name to the csv file. Other properties work fine.

Comment: Remove the Export-Csv part of the pipeline.  Does it display the Owner along with LastWriteTime, Directory and FullName?  Also see the updated answer to make sure you're using `-Input $_`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash table with Select-Object.

```
$dir_to_look="F:\"    
$month_backdate=$(Get-Date).AddDays(-7)  
Get-Childitem $dir_to_look -Recurse | ? { !($_.psiscontainer) -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $month_backdate } |
    Select-object LastWriteTime, Directory, FullName, @{n='Owner';e={(Get-ACL $_.FullName).owner}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir_to_look="F:\"    
$month_backdate=$(Get-Date).AddDays(-7)  
Get-Childitem $dir_to_look -Recurse | ? { !($_.psiscontainer) -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $month_backdate } |
Select-object LastWriteTime, Directory, FullName, @{n='Owner';e={(Get-ACL $_.FullName).owner}}
```